# android : How to iterate using cursor.moveToPosition(x)?

Tags: android, cursor

//How to iterate using cursor.moveToPosition(x) when Onclick of Random and NextTORandom Button is clicked?

//here is my code for Mydatabase.java. This file is used to fetch the single row from the database.

```
public Cursor getData(int _id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor =db.rawQuery("Select * from '"+DB_TABLE+"' where _id = ?", new    String[] { String.valueOf(_id)}); 

    if (cursor != null)
    {
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    }

    return cursor;
```

// here is my code for MyActivity.java

```
public void onClick(View v) {
cur=db.getData(position);
int firstpos=1; 
int lastpos=4;

switch(v.getId())
{

case R.id.NextToRandom :
{ 

if (cur != null && cur.getCount()> 0 && position < cur.getCount() && position != cur.getCount()){
cur.moveToPosition(position);
textView1.setText(""+cur.getString(1));// Display Columns 
position++;
cur.moveToNext();
}
if(cur.moveToPosition(lastpos))
{

cur.moveToPosition(firstpos); 
textView1.setText(""+cur.getString(1));
}
/*else
{
cur.moveToPosition(position); 
textView1.setText(""+cur.getString(1));
position++;
}*/


//display details code

}
break;
case R.id.random:
{
Random r = new Random();
int rnum = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
cur=db.getData(rnum);
setNewData(rnum);
}
}


}

private void setNewData (int xyz) {



}
```

//I want to loop through all the records by clicking Random_back_button,Random_button and Random_Next_button. How to implement this?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: please provide [sscce](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over a cursor like so:

```
Cursor cursor = ...; // get cursor from somewhere
for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext) {
    // your code here
}
```

Cursors do provide random access, so if you need to access a particular row, call `cursor.moveToPosition(int)`.

Answer (score -1):

Official Code here ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓

```
    // ------------------------------
    // android.database.DatabaseUtils
    // ------------------------------

    public static void dumpCursor(Cursor cursor, StringBuilder sb) {
        sb.append(">>>>> Dumping cursor " + cursor + "\n");
        if (cursor != null) {
            int startPos = cursor.getPosition();

            cursor.moveToPosition(-1);
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                dumpCurrentRow(cursor, sb);
            }
            cursor.moveToPosition(startPos);
        }
        sb.append("<<<<<\n");
    }
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)